# Python Pdb giving me a tracback and won't run

Tags: python, debugging, pdb

I set the `Pdb` debugger in my file as I always do like so `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` and now I keep getting this traceback. I'm not sure what is the issue, and I don't see anything online about this anywhere.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myfile.py", line 28, in <module>
    pdb.set_trace()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pdb.py", line 1251, in set_trace
    Pdb().set_trace(sys._getframe().f_back)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pdb.py",     line 63, in __init__
    cmd.Cmd.__init__(self, completekey, stdin, stdout)
TypeError: __init__() takes at most 2 arguments (4 given)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check whether you have your own `cmd.py`. That prevent import of standard library [`cmd`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cmd.html) module.

Try following command:

```
python -c "import cmd; print(cmd.__file__)"
```

It should print something like:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/cmd.py
```

or

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/cmd.pyc
```

If there's your own version of `cmd.py` or `cmd.pyc`, rename it.

Comment: This was exactly it. I was using ST2 with Rope and must have saved the cmd.py file to my directory. Thanks @falsetru!